# Multilingual SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing an Android app. I've put the SQLite file in res/raw.
It's working very well. Now I want to add other languages to my app, and therefore the application need to be translated.

What do you think is the easiest way to used translated DBs: modifying the original SQLite DB, or creating new ones and put them in like res/raw-fr, res/raw-de..?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not storing strings inside DB but only keys, which target strings from xml.

Comment: Actually I'm storing Recips.